# What are the dotted lines in between chat messages?

Tags: discussion, chat

I was chatting earlier and noticed dotted lines in between chat messages:
[image: Lines in chat]
What do they do?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109251/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-catchup-marker-in-chat

Comment: @balpha Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They appear when that chatroom screen has lost focus at the last message you read before going to another program or chatroom.  When you come back, the line shows you where you left off reading so you don't have to figure out what was said while you were doing something else.

Comment: Ah. Thanks so much!